Twilio Conversations and Catalog Content Template
I'm trying to send a Catalog Template from a Twilio Studio Flow, where Conversations is activated on the trigger side. However, I keep getting the following error:
Failure sending message: Unsupported Content Template Type.
Is there any workaround to successfully send Catalog Templates in this configuration? I'm using Conversations because of Flex integration.
Edit:
Adding a minimal reproducible example.
1. Create Content Template
{
    "friendly_name": "simple_catalog",
    "language": "es",
    "types": {
        "twilio/catalog": {
            "id": "XXXXXX", // Replace with your catalog ID
            "body": "Select.",
            "subtitle": "Subtitle",
            "title": "Products",
            "thumbnail_item_id": "id_1" // Replace with your thumbnail ID
        }
    }
}


2. Create Studio Flow:
{
  "description": "A New Flow",
  "states": [
    {
      "name": "Trigger",
      "type": "trigger",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "incomingMessage"
        },
        {
          "event": "incomingCall"
        },
        {
          "next": "send_catalog",
          "event": "incomingConversationMessage"
        },
        {
          "event": "incomingRequest"
        },
        {
          "event": "incomingParent"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "send_catalog",
      "type": "send-and-wait-for-reply",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "set_order_response",
          "event": "incomingMessage"
        },
        {
          "event": "timeout"
        },
        {
          "event": "deliveryFailure"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 250,
          "y": 230
        },
        "service": "{{trigger.message.InstanceSid}}",
        "channel": "{{trigger.message.ChannelSid}}",
        "from": "{{flow.channel.address}}",
        "message_type": "content_template",
        "content_sid": "HXX",// Replace with  actual simple_catalog SID
        "timeout": "3600"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "set_order_response",
      "type": "set-variables",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "next"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "variables": [
          {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "{{widgets.send_catalog.inbound.Order}}",
            "key": "order_response"
          }
        ],
        "offset": {
          "x": 250,
          "y": 470
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "initial_state": "Trigger",
  "flags": {
    "allow_concurrent_calls": true
  }
}

3. Send message to Whatsapp Sender:
After sending the message, check the Flow Log execution.
Look for a deliveryFailure event for the send_catalog widget.
Expand the entry and check Debugging Information > Detail: Failure sending message: Unsupported Content Template Type.

Can you please provide as much supporting details as possible? It would be helpful to see your Studio flow with the configuration of the widget that is supposed to send the template.

Thanks @IObert ,widget section is defined as :
{"name": "send_catalog", type": "send-and-wait-for-reply", "transitions": [{ "next": "send_welcome_list_picker", "event": "incomingMessage"},{"event": "timeout"}, {"event": "deliveryFailure"}],  "properties": { "offset": {: 80, "y": 300 },  "service": "{{trigger.message.InstanceSid}}",  "channel": "{{trigger.message.ChannelSid}}", "from": "{{flow.channel.address}}","message_type": "content_template", "content_sid": "{{flow.variables.CATALOG_TEMPLATE_SID}}", "timeout": "3600"}}.

However it appears that Catalog Template is not yet supported The Content Template Builder.

We're in process of rolling out the catalog and it will be available soon. For your case, I'm still not sure what you tried and in which error you ran. Can you please create a minimal reproducible example)? This would make it easier to help you.

Thank you for the update! I’ve added the minimal reproducible example as requested in my question post. Could you kindly provide an ETA for when the catalog will be available? It would be great to know when I can expect it to be ready.

My bad, it seems to be available now. Can you confirm that you followed all steps from this guide?

Yes, I've followed guide to create Content Template as shown on the reproducible example. However guide is still using Messaging API, my error is with Conversations API  via Studio Flow.

Can you confirm that you are able to send the product catalog message when using as mentioned above (i.e. messaging service instead of conversations API)?

Yes, it works with messaging API but I need conversations instead. My studio flow uses conversation due to Flex integration .

I just followed up with our development team and unfortunately the content type "twilio/catalog" is currently not supported in Conversations. You can find a full list of supported types in our docs.
Having said that, we're constantly adding new content types to the messaging and conversation service and this one in particular is on our roadmap.
